# What to call method which returns char* ( String in Java and char* in C++)?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have function in Java like

```
public boolean getIsIn();
public String getName();
```

in c++ I have wrapper functions like

```
 bool gPGIsIn(){
    JNIEnv* env = s3eEdkJNIGetEnv();
    return (bool)env->CallBooleanMethod(g_Obj, g_s3eGPGIsIn);
}
 char* gPGGetName(){
    JNIEnv* env = s3eEdkJNIGetEnv();
    // below is a problem, what to call
    //return (char*)env->CallWahtMethod(g_Obj, g_s3eGPGGetName);
}
```

where

```
static jmethodID g_s3eGPGIsIn = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getIsIn", "()Z");
static jmethodID g_s3eGPGGetName = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

What to call in line tagged like problem inside gPGGetName to call method which returns char* ( String in Java and char* in C++) ?

Comment: I don't know anything about the NDK, but isn't there a way to get a `std::string` out of it? Because that's the standard C++ string type.

Comment: You need to further define the "what" before the "how". I assume `gPGGetName` is to return a pointer to the first element of an array. Which character set and encoding should be used? Should the array be terminated in some way? What if the encoding produces what looks like the terminator in the middle of the string? How should the array be allocated and who should free it? If the character set does not support all the Unicode characters in the string, should unsupported characters be replaced with a substitution character, or be skipped, or should the function fail in some way?

Comment: Call it anything you like that makes sense to you. Not a real question.

Answer (score 1):

It returns a `String` object and you can use the [JNI string functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#string_operations) to convert that string to a `char*`:

```
char* gPGGetName() {
    jobject objStr = env->CallObjectMethod(g_Obj, g_s3eGPGGetName);
    jsize len = env->GetStringUTFLength(objStr);
    const char* strPtr = env->GetStringUTFChars(objStr, 0);
    char* buffer = (char*)malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
    memcpy(buffer, strPtr, len);
    buffer[len] = '\0';
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(objStr, strPtr);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the return value would be a pointer to a 0x00-terminated Unicode string with a modified UTF-8 encoding. Unless specifically designed to do so, the caller would not be able to process the modified UTF-8 encoding. (The default Android encoding is standard UTF-8.) It could also work if the string contains only ASCII characters 1-127 (the encodings are identical for U+00001 to U+0007F) but the question does not state that constraint nor is there any code to check it. And, the caller should free the string by calling `free`.

Comment: `* sizeof(char)` doesn't make sense because all the functions involved use a number of bytes. Now, `sizeof(char)` is always 1 by definition, no matter how many bits are in a char or byte. Therefore, as you intend, `buffer[len]` will always write a '\0' immediately after the part written by `memcpy`.

Comment: @TomBlodget I know that the `* sizeof(char)` is redundant, but it'll be optimized out anyways and my `malloc`s **always** include a `sizeof` for clarity and security reasons (what if a data structure's size changes?). Also, thanks for that explanation about Java's modified UTF-8. I couldn't find anything in the JNI docs about whether or not the 0-terminator is included, so I'm adding it manually in my code.

Comment: **BUG** You need to use `GetStringUTFLength` not `GetStringLength`. "You win €100" is 12 codepoints, `GetStringLength` will say it has 12 UTF-16 code units and `GetStringUTFLength` will say it needs 14 bytes for the modified UTF-8 encoding. It'll make a big difference to leave off the last two bytes!